# required DLLs for my program's exe file

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I've created a program in c++ using the following header files:

iostream.h

Windows.h

Vector and

time.h

I can run my program's executable file in my computer but when I try to open it on other PCs I get dll missing problems. When i tried downloading the missing DLLs and try to open my program, i get the error "0xc00007b" , "The application was unable to start correctly". How do i fix this problem? There were a lot of dll files with same name but different versions so i wasn't sure and i chose the one which suited the computer's bit.

Comment: faster of all you use *crt*. and your *crt* version  not installed on other PCs

Comment: You can either add the dependencies from the source computer alongside to the destination one. Or install `vcrt` on the target machine. Otherwise you can build statically. However since `msvs 14` it prevents static building of the `crt`.

Comment: @RbMm I can't understand what you meant, i'm still in new comers stage

Comment: @Raindrop7 whats a vcrt and idk what my dependencies are.

Comment: You can use a dependency walker to locate all the dependencies on your source machine needed by your program and then copy them to the target. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh.aspx

Comment: @Raindrop7: Dependency Walker is the wrong tool. It hasn't been updated in ages, will no longer work reliably (starting with Windows 7), and can only reliably evaluate static imports. Even in profile mode, there is no guarantee that your tests did follow all code paths performing explicit library loading. It also cannot determine COM server requirements, as far as I know.

Comment: @Raindrop7: An alternative to not having a build system? No, there is no alternative to not having a build system. And when you do have a build system, you won't ask questions like this one.

Comment: @Raindrop7: You don't need Dependency Walker, or any other tool to determine the set of libraries you need, because your build system already knows.

Comment: @IInspectable: The OP talks about redistributing his application that depends on some dlls. So he/she wanted to know what dll files should be copied.

Comment: @Raindrop7: Exactly. And since they aren't using a build system, they are in a situation where they do not understand their dependencies. And have to invest time to come up with a possibly incomplete solution. You could [enable loader snaps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/junfeng/2006/11/20/debugging-loadlibrary-failures/) to determine at least some library dependencies. Loader snaps work on any support version of Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say which compiler you are using, so I'll assume you use Visual Studio.

I think you need to install the VC redistributable package for the VS version you are using. For example for VS 2015 you have [this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145).

Anyway, in the VS installation DVD there is usually a copy of that package. And it is redistributable, so you can redistribute it to your client machines.

Comment: Yea, i'm using VS. I guess that was the problem and using `/MT` also helped me.

Comment: @Teisted: Well, sure, never distribute a debug build. Mind that the debug version of the VC runtime is *not* redistributable, so you are not allowed to install it on third party machines.

Comment: This is no longer strictly a requirement. Starting with Windows 10, the CRT is part of the OS.

Comment: @IInspectable: That is nice! Do you have any reference for that? The only one I can find is [this post](https://www.howtogeek.com/256245/why-are-there-so-many-microsoft-visual-c-redistributables-installed-on-my-pc/), but it states that only VC2012 and VC2013 are included. Maybe others are installing through the montly Windows Updates?

Comment: [Introducing the Universal CRT](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using Visual Studio IDE. Open Project properties, go to C/C++ section, Code Generation. Then choose multithreaded (debug) `/MT` or `/MTd` option for Runtime Library (without DLL). This way you will compile static runtime library and your EXE will not need external (compiler) DLLs.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. It works around it. Static linking has downsides to it, the most dramatic one is probably, that you have opted out of ever exchanging CRT resources across module boundaries. This may not be an issue for the OP, but it is in general.

Comment: @IInspectable And why it exist in Visual Studio - to have problems? I have always used this option and never had problem until now.

Comment: The option exists in case you want or need it. A developer will have to determine, which option is applicable in any given scenario. While it may not matter much for small or personal projects, completely disabling the ability to ever safely move CRT resources across module boundaries is certainly not a wise choice for larger projects. There are other downsides to static linking, and in general, it is more troublesome than dynamic linking.

Comment: @IInspectable Please explain me what is the difference (technically and in practice) between "static" linking of compiler's runtime and the SAME runtime in a form of DLL. The code of runtime is identical. The difference is whether it is embedded in EXE file or dynamically linked to one or more DLLs. Of course, any WinAPI calls are made with dynamic linking to User32.DLL, GDI.DLL, Kernel.DLL, etc.

Comment: Here is [one difference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/potential-errors-passing-crt-objects-across-dll-boundaries). A fairly substantial one, too.

Comment: @IInspectable Who says that the OP is (or I am) making project with EXE+DLL file? When the project is only in 1 EXE file without DLL, do you think that the example from your link can be valid?

Comment: You are inverting responsibilities. Who says that the OP *weren't* using other DLLs? You have to answer the general case, unless there is an explicit statement that relaxes requirements. And even if the OP were compiling a single EXE, statically linking reduces serviceability. This is particularly true with the CRT being now (as of Windows 10) an OS component, rather than a compiler component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156889/discussion-between-i486-and-iinspectable).